# Ignore date conversion warnings (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have CSV file, contains date field that has either:
1. %Y-%m-%d
2. %m/%d/%Y
3. empty string

The code I use for importing:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
SET EpStartDate = IFNULL (DATE(@v_EpStartDate), STR_TO_DATE(@v_EpStartDate, '%m/%d/%Y')),
...
```

But this code throws warning about every `%m/%d/%Y` date, and about each empty cell.

It's very important to me to show only crucial warnings, when the data is wrong, like if the date is `03/18/20095`.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable using custom function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PARSE_DATE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION PARSE_DATE ( str VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    IF str in ('',' ','.') THEN RETURN null;
    ELSEIF str like '__/__/____' THEN RETURN STR_TO_DATE(str, '%m/%d/%Y');
    ELSEIF str like '__-__-____' THEN RETURN STR_TO_DATE(str, '%m-%d-%Y');
    ELSE RETURN DATE(str); /*may throw a warning*/
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the IFNULL function details here.[enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). The code

```
IFNULL(expr1, expr2)
```

returns expr1 if expr1 is NOT null, and expr2 if expr1 IS null.

So when the date variable is not empty, it is returned as it is (without checking for format, as that is done in expr2 in your code above) and when it is empty, it is checked against the date format.

Thus your program gives you warnings because you are checking for date formats on empty strings and at the same time input the non-empty strings without checking for their date format.